# Cannot load ZIP compressed fonts since ZIP PHP extension is not available

Tags: php

I want to use this [Figlet](http://bolknote.ru/files/figlet/) and i get the error: `Cannot load ZIP compressed fonts since ZIP PHP extension is not available`

what kind of error is this, as i cant find the error

i have php 5.2.17

Comment: It's the kind of error that tells you to install the php_zip module if possible if you want to use Zip compressed fonts.

Comment: i just had to unzip the font and use it like that ; easy

Comment: tricky stuff with these fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i just unzipped the files, and used them.